# umount: device is busy. Why?

Tags: mount

When running `umount /path` I get:

```
umount: /path: device is busy.
```

The filesystem is huge, so `lsof +D /path` is not a realistic option.

`lsof /path`, `lsof +f -- /path`, and `fuser /path` all return nothing. `fuser -v /path` gives:

```
                  USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/path:            root     kernel mount /path
```

which is normal for all unused mounted file systems.

`umount -l` and `umount -f` is not good enough for my situation.

How do I figure out why the kernel thinks this filesystem is busy?

Comment: Is your shell's current directory on the mountpoint path?

Comment: No. Then fuser would say so.

Comment: You actually want `fuser -vm /path` ...

Comment: For  umount `--force` will try harder to unmount and `-v` or `-vvv` even will reaveal more what is the problem with mount. So try: `umount -vvv --force /babdmount`

Comment: @derobert: Which in my case revealed an active swapfile and was the solution to my version of the "device busy" problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 184, accepted):

It seems the cause for my issue was the `nfs-kernel-server` was exporting the directory. The `nfs-kernel-server` probably goes behind the normal open files and thus is not listed by `lsof` and `fuser`.

When I stopped the `nfs-kernel-server` I could `umount` the directory.

I have made a page with examples of all solutions so far here: http://oletange.blogspot.com/2012/04/umount-device-is-busy-why.html

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question instead of abandoning it upon implementing your solution.  Your answer helped me sort out a similarly exported NFS share.

Comment: This same issue can also occur if you've set up loopback devices on the filesystem - for example if /dev/loop0 is backed by a file in /path.

Comment: I had to `sudo service samba stop` first, your answer really helped out !

Comment: This post reminded me that I had the nfs service running after several hours of trying to figure this out. In RHEL6/CentOS6, use `sudo service nfs stop` and you may (not) need to also do `sudo exportfs -u` to unexport. Remember to then `sudo exportfs -r` and `sudo service nfs start` to re-export and restart the service.

Comment: In my case it was not necessary to stop the nfs server, just `exportfs -u` the directory in question.

Comment: Great list of solutions. I have a new one for you: anonymous inodes.
See the relevant heading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45782183/5353461).

Comment: I had the same problem as you, however, the `fuser -v` in your question led me to the solution before even scrolling down.  In my case, the kernel nfs daemon *was* listed in the fuser output.  `[root@system ~]# fuser -v /raid
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/raid:               root     kernel mount /raid
                     root     kernel knfsd /raid`

Comment: Expanding on @BCran's comment, I had a swap file there. `swapoff -a` did the trick for me.

Comment: wow this was my exact problem. `nfs-kernel-server` was running. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 52):

To add to [BruceCran](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/15815/brucecran)'s [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15024/umount-device-is-busy-why#comment43883_15027) above, the cause for my manifestation of this problem just now was a *stale* loopback mount.  I'd already checked the output of `fuser -vm <mountpoint>`/`lsof +D <mountpoint>`, `mount` and `cat /proc/mounts`, checked whether some old nfs-kernel-server was running, turned off quotas, attempted (but failed) a `umount -f <mountpoint>` and all but resigned myself to abandoning 924 days' uptime before finally checking the output of `losetup` and finding two stale configured-but-not-mounted loopbacks:

```
parsley:/mnt# cat /proc/mounts 
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
none /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0
none /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0
udev /dev tmpfs rw,size=10240k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/mapper/stuff-root / ext3 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
tmpfs /lib/init/rw tmpfs rw,nosuid,mode=755 0 0
usbfs /proc/bus/usb usbfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw 0 0
/dev/dm-2 /mnt/big ext3 rw,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered,jqfmt=vfsv0,usrjquota=aquota.user 0 0
```

then

```
parsley:/mnt# fuser -vm /mnt/big/
parsley:/mnt# lsof +D big
parsley:/mnt# umount -f /mnt/big/
umount2: Device or resource busy
umount: /mnt/big: device is busy
umount2: Device or resource busy
umount: /mnt/big: device is busy

parsley:/mnt# losetup -a    
/dev/loop0: [fd02]:59 (/mnt/big/dot-dropbox.ext2)
/dev/loop1: [fd02]:59 (/mnt/big/dot-dropbox.ext2)

parsley:/mnt# losetup -d /dev/loop0
parsley:/mnt# losetup -d /dev/loop1
parsley:/mnt# losetup -a
parsley:/mnt# umount big/
parsley:/mnt#
```

A [Gentoo forum post](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-3928386.html#3928386) also lists swapfiles as a potential culprit; although swapping to files is probably pretty rare these days, it can't hurt to check the output of `cat /proc/swaps`.  I'm not sure whether quotas could ever prevent an unmount — I was clutching at straws.

Comment: All 924 days uptime means is that you need to update your kernel patches :-)

Comment: +1 for mentioning swap files, they _do_ block unmounting, and are pretty much undetectable if you are not checking them directly.

Comment: I also had a stale loop0, but `losetup -d /dev/loop0` would NOT actually detach it. running `-a` still showed it there; never got it to go away.

Answer (score 35):

Instead of using lsof to crawl through the file system, just use the total list of open files and grep it. I find this returns must faster, although it's less accurate. It should get the job done.

```
lsof | grep '/path'
```

Comment: lsof /path looks through the path only.

Comment: I didn't say `lsof /path`, I said `lsof | grep '/path'`. The difference is that lsof with no arguments shows all open files using some sort of cache table, and grep is very fast at searching through it. The things you tried with lsof make it scan through the file system which takes a long time.

Comment: Like I said: `lsof /path` looks at the path only. It does not look at every single file. It is often much faster than `lsof | grep /path` (in my unscientific test it was 20 times faster YMMV) since it does not look at all open files but only the files for that path.

Comment: I'm not sure of the what the technical difference is, but while investigating a stale NFS mount, `lsof /path` yielded nothing whereas `lsof | grep /path` showed me the process that was holding open files and preventing me from unmounting the volume.

Answer (score 24):

For me, the offending process was a daemon running in a chroot. Because it was in a chroot, `lsof` and `fuser` wouldn't find it.

If you suspect you have something left running in a chroot, `sudo ls -l /proc/*/root | grep chroot` will find the culprit (replace "chroot" with the path to the chroot).

Comment: Nice, and in FreeBSD I did this: `sudo ls -l /proc/*/status | grep HOST` where HOST is the hostname of the jail

Comment: On my system (Mint Qiana) `lsof /mountpoint` and `fuser /mountpoint` both find a process even if chrooted.

Answer (score 24):

#### Open files

Processes with open files are the usual culprits. Display them:

```
lsof +f -- <mountpoint or device>
```

There is an advantage to using  `/dev/<device>` rather than `/mountpoint`: a mountpoint will disappear after an `umount -l`, or it may be hidden by an overlaid mount.

`fuser` can also be used, but to my mind `lsof` has a more useful output. However `fuser` is useful when it comes to killing the processes causing your dramas so you can get on with your life.

List files on `<mountpoint>` (see caveat above):

```
fuser -vmM <mountpoint>
```

Interactively kill only processes with files open for writing:

```
fuser -vmMkiw <mountpoint>
```

After remounting read-only (`mount -o remount,ro <mountpoint>`), it is safe(r) to kill all remaining processes:

```
fuser -vmMk <mountpoint>
```

#### Mountpoints

The culprit can be the kernel itself. Another filesystem mounted on the filesystem you are trying to `umount` will cause grief. Check with:

```
mount | grep <mountpoint>/
```

For loopback mounts, also check the output of:

```
losetup -la
```

#### Anonymous inodes (Linux)

[Anonymous inodes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4508998/5353461) can be created by:

- Temporary files (`open` with `O_TMPFILE`)
- [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) watches
- [eventfd]
- [eventpoll]
- [timerfd]

These are the most elusive type of pokemon, and appear in `lsof`'s `TYPE` column as `a_inode` (which is undocumented in the  [`lsof` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html)).

They won't appear in `lsof +f -- /dev/<device>`, so you'll need to:

```
lsof | grep a_inode
```

For killing processes holding anonymous inodes, see: [List current inotify watches (pathname, PID)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/386877/143394).

Comment: Your fuser suggestion was very helpful when booted into the Arch Linux installation media which doesn't come with lsof by default.

Comment: this answer is fantastic. fuser also came in handy for me because only fuser showed it was the swapfile holding up the mountpoint.

Answer (score 7):

For fuser to report on the PIDs holding a mount open you have to use -m

```
fuser -m /path
```

Comment: True, but irrelevant: `lsof /path` provides the same list of PIDs as `fuser -m /path`.

Comment: `fuser -M /path` will check whether `/path` is a mountpoint.

Comment: This is the only thing that actually worked for me. `umount -f` did nothing. `lsof` didn't work either. The only weird thing is it prints a `c` after the PID but just ignore that.

Answer (score 6):

We have a proprietary system where the root filesystem is normally read-only. Occasionally, when files have to be copied over, it is remounted read-write:

```
mount -oremount,rw /
```

And then remounted back:

```
mount -oremount,ro /
```

This time however, `mount` kept giving  the `mount: / is busy` error. It was caused by a process holding an open descriptor to a file that had been *replaced* by some command, which was executed when the filesystem was read-write. The important line from `lsof -- /` output happens to be (names have been changed):

```
replicate  1719 admin DEL REG 8,5  204394 /opt/gns/lib/replicate/modules/md_es.so
```

Notice the `DEL` in the output. Simply restarting the process holding on to the deleted file resolved the issue.

Comment: So the summary is: process having a file opened that was removed. Good input.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue, and it turned out that there were active screen sessions in the background I didn't know about. I connected to the other active screen session and its shell wasn't even currently sitting in the mounted directory. Killing those other shell sessions fixed the issue for me.

Just thought I'd share my resolution.

Answer (score 4):

`lsof` and `fuser` didn't give me anything either.

After a process of renaming all possible directories to .old and rebooting the system every time after I made changes I found one particular directory (relating to postfix) that was responsible.

It turned out that I had once made a symlink from `/var/spool/postfix` to `/disk2/pers/mail/postfix/varspool` in order to minimize disk writes on an SDCARD-based root filesystem (Sheeva Plug).

With this symlink, even after stopping the `postfix` and `dovecot` services (both `ps aux` as well as `netstat -tuanp` didn't show anything related) I was not able to `unmount /disk2/pers`.

When I removed the symlink and updated the `postfix` and `dovecot` config files to point directly to the new dirs on `/disk2/pers/` I was able to successfully stop the services and `unmount` the directory.

Next time I will look more closely at the output of:

```
ls -lR /var | grep ^l | grep disk2
```

The above command will recursively list all symbolic links in a directory tree (here starting at `/var`) and filter out those names that point to a specific target mount point (here disk2).

Comment: `find /var -type l -lname '*disk2*' -printf '%p -> %l\n'` does the same as the `ls` pipe

Answer (score 3):

As [@LawrenceC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15024/umount-device-is-busy-why#comment20179_15024) suggested, If your shell's current working directory is on the mountpoint path, you will get the "device is busy" error.

```
ubuntu@myip:~/efs$ sudo umount ~/efs
umount.nfs4: /home/ubuntu/efs: device is busy
```

`cd` to a location other than the mountpoint to resolve the error.

Comment: OP expressely stated that his current working directory was *not* on the mount path.

Comment: @guntbert since [comments are ephemeral](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312002/402815) and neither the question or answers mention the issue of whether the current working directory is on the mount path, I added it as an explicit answer.

Comment: @guntbert you are right, however it is not unlikely that this is the problem for someone coming here from a search engine (like it was for me).

Answer (score 2):

Today the problem was an open socket (specifically `tmux`):

```
mount /mnt/disk
export TMPDIR=/mnt/disk
tmux
<<detatch>>
umount /mnt/disk
umount: /mnt/disk: device is busy.
lsof | grep /mnt/disk
tmux      20885             root    6u     unix 0xffff880022346300        0t0    3215201 /mnt/disk/tmux-0/default
```

Comment: This is really absurd, but yea tmux was culprit for me too!

Answer (score 2):

I have a couple of `bind` and `overlay` mounts under my mount that were blocking me, check the tab completion for the mount-point you want to unmount. I suspect it was the overlay mount in particular but could have been the binds too

Answer (score 1):

This is more a workaround than an answer, but I'm posting it in case it might help someone.

In my case I was trying to modify the LVM as I wanted to make the /var partition bigger, so I needed to umount it. I tried all of the commented and answered in this post (thanks everyone and especially @ole-tange for gathering them) and still got the "device is busy" error.

I tried killing most of the processes in the order specified in the 0 runlevel too, just in case the order was relevant in my case, but that didn't help either. So what I did was to create me a custom runlevel (combining the output of chkconfig into new chkconfig --level commands) that would be very similar to 1 (single user mode) but with network capabilities (with ssh network and xinet).

As I was using redhat, runlevel 4 is marked as "unused/user defined", so I used that one, and run 
`init 4`
In my case this was ok as I needed to reboot the server in any case, but probably that will be the case of anyone tweaking the disks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had earlier done a `zpool import` of a file-based pool on that drive. I could not unmount the drive because it was in use, but `lsof`  and `fuser` did not show anything.

The solution was to do `sudo zpool export mypool` and then unmount.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was docker that was holding the file. I am running ZFS, and after lazy umounting the volume, I got an error message:

```
mount: /tank: /dev/zd112 already mounted or mount point busy.
```

The investigation

```
fuser /dev/zd112
Cannot stat file /proc/32130/fd/4: Stale file handle
Cannot stat file /proc/32130/fd/5: Stale file handle
Cannot stat file /proc/32130/fd/6: Stale file handle
Cannot stat file /proc/32130/fd/7: Stale file handle
Cannot stat file /proc/32130/fd/11: Stale file handle
```

Running `ps aux |grep 32130` results:

```
999      32130  4.1  1.2 10784420 1241840 ?    Ssl  Jun20 10055:41 mysqld
```

Which is not a mysql run in the same userspace, but within a container.

Running `docker ps |grep mysql` yields

```
3c6c907a28db        mysql:5.7                                                                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 months ago       Up 5 months         33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3336->3306/tcp   zabbix_db_1_5e72b12e41d2
```

Next you can run:

```
docker stop 3c6c907a28db
```