# List current inotify watches (pathname, PID)

Tags: linux, lsof, inotify, unmounting, fuser

How do I get a list of:

- Pathnames currently being watched by `inotify`, and
- PID of the process watching

I ask because I have found that [`syncthing`](https://syncthing.net/)'s `inotify` watches were preventing my disk from being unmounted.

As can be seen below, nothing appears in `lsof` or `fuser` listings.

I guessed well with `syncthing`... How do I remove the guesswork in future if a disk won't unmount due to `inotify`?

---

```
# umount /media/backup
umount: /media/backup: target is busy.
# lsof +f -- /media/backup/
# echo $?
1
# fuser -vmM /media/backup/
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/media/backup:       root     kernel mount /media/backup
# systemctl stop syncthing@ravi
# umount /media/backup
# echo $?
0
```

Comment: Relevant: [Who's consuming my inotify resources?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15509/86440)

Comment: From my reading of that, it's possible to know which processes have inotify watches, but not what they are watching. I hope to be wrong!

Comment: That’s my impression too. Either way, once this question is answered it would be worth updating [How do I find out which processes are preventing unmounting of a device?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3109/86440)

Comment: @StephenKitt I've done that [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386960/143394), trying to collate all the relevant infomation into a single answer. Let me know if I've missed anything.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the `fdinfo` for the fd of the watch can be useful:

```
$ readlink /proc/$(pgrep inotify)/fd/3
anon_inode:inotify
$ cat /proc/$(pgrep inotify)/fdinfo/3
pos:    0
flags:  00
mnt_id: 11
inotify wd:1 ino:357a sdev:700000 mask:fff ignored_mask:0 fhandle-bytes:8 fhandle-type:1 f_handle:7a35000000000000
```

The `sdev` seems to be the major:minor device number combination, as seen in the output of `lsblk`, for example:

```
$ lsblk | grep 7
loop0    7:0    0  80.5M  1 loop /snap/core/2462
```

(I was indeed monitoring `/snap/core/2462`.)

For my `/dev/sda1` which is `8:1`, the output looked like so:

```
pos:    0
flags:  00
mnt_id: 11
inotify wd:1 ino:aae1b sdev:800001 mask:fff ignored_mask:0 fhandle-bytes:8 fhandle-type:1 f_handle:1bae0a0038e16969
```

This should be sufficient to find out what's blocking unmounting, even though the specific directories or files being watched aren't listed.

Comment: Great lead. Using `mnt_id` as an index into `/proc/[pid]/mountinfo` would give the mountpoint directory. How to efficiently perform this check for all processes (irrespective of name)?

Comment: [man proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) says `sdev: The ID of the device where the target file resides (in
                     hexadecimal).`  It also explains `mnt_id` and the `mountinfo` file.

Answer (score 2):

(WIP Answer)

Thanks to [muru's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386880/143394) for the kickstart.

Using the information in `/proc/[pid]/fdinfo/[fd#]`:

- Get mountpoint pathname and device using `mnt_id` as an index into `/proc/[pid]/mountinfo` or [possibly use a global mountinfo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/387784/143394)
- Convert `ino` to decimal
- Lookup pathnames from inode:

  - [`btrfs`](https://serverfault.com/a/869356/322507) (requires pathname)
  - [`ext4`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35310/143394) (requires device, possibly via [Interpret `sdev` field in /proc/<PID>/fdinfo/<FD>](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/387086/143394) )

Possibly  [lsof: list only files of a particular type](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/386993/143394) with `a_inode`.

Too slow as a shell script with all the `grep`ing. Perhaps [system call interface to /proc information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45951874/5353461).

Comment: I think I have exactly what you want, unless I am mistaken: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15509/whos-consuming-my-inotify-resources/502812#502812