# lsof: list only files of a particular type

Tags: linux, lsof

The [`lsof` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html) is a bugger to read. I've tried, but wonder if I've missed something.

Is there a way without using pipes to have `lsof` list only files of a given `TYPE`?

In particular, I'm interested in the `a_inode` type *which isn't listed anywhere in the manual* (Grrr!)

Comment: I would `lsof | grep 'a_inode'`

Comment: Hi Tom,this may help to understand why is not listed anywhere, if you can read the sources, `a_inode` is listed in `lsof_4.89_src/dialects/linux/dnode.c:633` and since this is a dialect it is kinda related with some of these types : `BLK,CHR,DIR,FIFO,REG...` you can try reading again the man to see how to show one of these and maybe this will work with the `a_inode` as well. Hope it helps

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: it's much slower that way which is why I said no pipes. @Christopher thanks but I couldn't work out how to limit to only 
type `DIR` (as an example).

Comment: The reason to filter, and why the suggestion of @RomanPerekhrest is slow, is because lsof does a lot of stuff, including listing sockets and network connections. I don't know if it does DNS lookups and stuff for that too, but that definitely makes it slow. IF we could just filter on TYPE, that would exclude a lot of work for lsof