# How to determine why "target is busy" (why it won't unmount)?

Tags: linux, mount, cache

My USB drive is refusing to unmount:

```
# umount /mnt
umount: /mnt: target is busy
```

I believe this *might* be something to do with it catching up with disk caching, after some particularly intensive opperations.

1. Is there any way to determine if this is the case.  Ie: is there any way to determine *why* the `target is busy`?
2. Assuming this is disk caching; Is there any way to find out how much is left to go, or get it to notify me when it's done?

---

I believe I caused this after a script speant approximately 10 hours replacing duplicate files with hard links, the 10 hours were spend removing duplicates not finding them.  Immagine this on loop:

```
rm "$DUPLICATE"
ln "$BASE_FILE" "$DUPLICATE"
```

This has effectivly deleted 1.1 million files with a total of 300 GB space.  In short, I've just been hammering the file system, particularly it's meta data.

Comment: Regarding the specifics of your question, if there’s dirty cached data waiting to be written to the drive, `umount` will wait for that to happen; it won’t fail with the “target is busy” message. That error means there’s something actively holding a resource on the target file system (open files, current directory, loop mounts, swap file etc.).

Comment: @StephenKitt Okay, I'd already seen the page you linked, but on second viewing I realise I'd missed this particular answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/15026/20140 .  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this was `mlocate`.  That's going to be annoying if it tries that every time I plug one of these drives in.  I've just removed it.