# umount: /home: target is busy

Tags: centos, filesystems, mount, lvm, unmounting

```
umount /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-home
umount: /home: target is busy
```

I looked at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15024/umount-device-is-busy-why) answer and found [this useful page](http://oletange.blogspot.com/2012/04/umount-device-is-busy-why.html)
I was unable to solve my problem before posting here.

My `/var` directory is full. `/var` is on a lvm.  Last night, I went to increase the size of `/var` and accidentally executed `lvextend -L+50G /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-home` when I should have `lvextend -L +50G dev/mapper/nvmeVg-var` oops.

So no big deal right? `lvextend -L-50G /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-home` results in

```
Size may not be negative.  Invalid argument for --size: -50G.  Error during parsing of command line:
```

So then I see to [shrink a non root volume](https://www.rootusers.com/lvm-resize-how-to-decrease-an-lvm-partition/) I must umount the device first.  Sure no problem: `/umount /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-home` results in

```
umount: /home: target is busy
```

So I `lsof /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-home` and get lots of output.  So if I am unable to umount because /home has files in use, then I tried `lsof | grep /dev/mapper/nvme` returned nothing.  I was expecting to see the total number of files open.  Then I tried `/lsof +f -- /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-home` which returned alot of files currently in use.  Fine.  I then notice /home is mounted to multiple volume groups?(still uncertain on terminology).  That's odd.  Doesn't look right.  Could this be a second issue with in my issue?

```
nvme0n1         259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1     259:1    0   953M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2     259:2    0  46.6G  0 part 
│ └─nvmeVg-var  253:2    0    50G  0 lvm  /var
├─nvme0n1p3     259:3    0  46.6G  0 part 
│ ├─nvmeVg-var  253:2    0    50G  0 lvm  /var
│ ├─nvmeVg-home 253:3    0   150G  0 lvm  /home
│ └─nvmeVg-root 253:4    0   100G  0 lvm  
├─nvme0n1p4     259:4    0  46.6G  0 part 
│ └─nvmeVg-home 253:3    0   150G  0 lvm  /home
├─nvme0n1p5     259:5    0  46.6G  0 part 
│ └─nvmeVg-home 253:3    0   150G  0 lvm  /home
├─nvme0n1p6     259:6    0  46.6G  0 part 
│ └─nvmeVg-root 253:4    0   100G  0 lvm  
├─nvme0n1p7     259:7    0  46.6G  0 part 
│ └─nvmeVg-root 253:4    0   100G  0 lvm  
├─nvme0n1p8     259:8    0  46.6G  0 part 
│ └─nvmeVg-home 253:3    0   150G  0 lvm  /home
├─nvme0n1p9     259:9    0  46.6G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p10    259:10   0  46.6G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p11    259:11   0  46.6G  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p12    259:12   0     1G  0 part
```

I feel like it is wise to pause and reach out for help at this point.

Comment: `lvextend` can only increase the size. This has nothing to do with being mounted. Try `lvreduce` or `lvresize` instead, but be **very** careful not to reduce too much. The `lsof` command, without options, doesn't print the device on which a file is located, therefore your grepping for *nvme* returns nothing. /home is not mounted multiple times, but is spread over multiple physical volumes. In short, you have no issue, just a slight misunderstanding how things work.

Comment: One way of avoiding damage by reducing the volume too much is by adding the `-r` option. It also resizes the filesystem. If /home is XFS, however, the command might refuse working, since XFS can't be reduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably you are logged in to the system as a regular user. When a regular user logs on, they occupy the `/home` as part of the path to their home directory.

You must login as `root` in order to unmount `/home`. The `root` user account has a home directory of `/root` therefore is not affected by `/home`. Also make sure that no other regular user is logged before you attempt to unmount `/home`

Then use `lvresize` command:

```
lvresize -r -L -50G /dev/mapper/nvmeVg-home
```

**Explanation:**

lvresize command will do four things:

1. Unmount the partition `/dev/mapper/nvmeVg-home`
2. Deduct 50GB of disk space from LV which will be credited back into VG (-L -50G)
3. Check the file system by calling resizefs (-r)
4. Then remounts the partition `/dev/mapper/nvmeVg-home`

Comment: Unfortunately, unmounting doesn't solve OP's problem. `lvextend` still doesn't accept negative sizes.

Comment: You must use lvresize command

Comment: Correct, and mounting is not the issue here.

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: I am logged in as root. Nice! This worked! YAS! Thank you so much!

Comment: Nitpicking: `lvresize` doesn't unmount nor remount the filesystem. If the filesystem can be shrunk (XFS can't), this is done while it's mounted.